# what's the correct image src path to display the image in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

For eg,  I wrote my own Wordpress plugin that uses the Transient API's to retrieve the total count of Facebook fans and I want to display a Facebook icon, adjacent to the total Facebook fan count on the side bar of my wordpress theme.

In my code I put

```
<p><img src="../../transientlabel/facebook.png" alt="Facebook">
```

as my transientlabel is my custom plugin folder.  However, wordpress did not like that so I'm clueless as to why Wordpress wouldn't allow me to do this..

I confirmed that the icon image above does exist and it's located in that folder certainly.

Does anybody know what I can do to get around this trivial problem?

Comment: Dont forget img tags end with a slash `...book"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p><img src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'facebook.png' , __FILE__ ); ?>" alt="Facebook"></p>
```